# Sweave/r - omit initial `>` in code chunks with `echo=true`?

Tags: r, sweave

I'm very new to sweave and I feel this will be an easy question, but I'm struggling to solve it myself (googling `omit ">" Sweave` doesn't really work because I can't search for ">"!).

I'm including a short script into my document:

```
<<echo=true, results=hide, eval=false>>=
# This is a simple script.
print('Hello World!\n')
@
```

I basically want the script to appear verbatim in the document, using whatever Sweave's "code" environment is. I don't want to evaluate it - it's just there to demonstrate how one might write a script utilising the functions in the package this document is for.

However, this produces the following in the output document:

```
> # This is a simple script
> print('Hello World!\n')
```

Is there some way to omit the `>` ? Is this the right way to put a script into a Sweave document, or is there some other environment that is meant to be used? (I can use a `\begin{verbatim}`, but it seemed to me that I should use Sweave commands if possible for code chunks).

I just want the output to be

```
# This is a simple script.
print('Hello World!\n')
```

Comment: It disappears when you switch to knitr...

Comment: I agree with Vincent Zoonekynd. *especially* if you are new to `Sweave` just go straight to `knitr`. I could understand if someone is very used to `Sweave` they want to stick with it, but even then you can ask `knitr` to emulate `Sweave`. Simply put, `Sweave` is a subset of `knitr`.

Comment: You will have to use a verbatim environment to keep the comments. Last question in FAQ is about parsing comments through Sweave - no go.

Comment: @XuWang: a minor correction: `knitr` is not a strict superset of Sweave until version 0.4, which will be released soon (the main missing feature was concordance, but that is irrelevant to the question here).

Comment: @Yihui thank you for the correction. Great, I'll be looking forward to 0.4!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try changing the `prompt` and `continue` options,
which define the `>` and `+` characters.

```
options(continue=" ", prompt=" ")
```

Comment: Thanks for this option. It did answer the question I asked, although based on all the comments I'll try `knitr` (never knew what exactly it was, but now I know Sweave is a subset of it I'm totally up for it). cheers!

Comment: Note this solution still leaves one space in each line in the code, but we cannot set `options(prompt = '')`; `knitr` completely get rid of the prompts by default (no spaces). I made this `knitr` FAQ 6: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/FAQ.md

Answer (score 6):

I like Vincent's first idea using `knitr`.

```
install.packages("knitr")
library(knitr)
```

Here's a sample Rnw.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage{Sweave}

\title{Test case}
\author{romunov}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

<<eval = FALSE, echo = TRUE>>=
# This is a simple script.
print('Hello World!\n')
@


\end{document}
```

And then

```
knit("coffee.Rnw")
```

Convert your .tex file into something pretty, and you get

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for that - I accepted Vincent's answer because it did answer the exact question I asked, although now that I've been alerted to the existence of `knitr` I think I'll use that. cheers!